# How To Pass a JavaScript Function to Plotly-Dash Ag-Grid rowStyle or getRowStyles Property

Tags: python, ag-grid, plotly-dash, dash-ag-grid

Is it possible to somehow pass a JavaScript function to the rowStyle or getRowStyles attribute, similarily to the way I can pass a JavaScript function to the cellStyle attribute?

I'm trying to dynamically update the row styles based on the data in that row and I cannot use the styleConditions mechanism since the rowStyle is a continuous function of my row data.

I'm trying to achieve something of the likes:

`dag.AgGrid(rowStyle={'function': 'getMyRowStyle(params)'})`

I'm trying to dynamically set the css background property of the rows like in the image attached.

I currenty solved it by updating the individual cell styles but it is a lot more complex and very problematic when feeding the grid live data since only the cells that change redraw. This is why I'm trying to find a solution using the row styles instead of the cell styles.

[orderbook with depth bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHif5.png)